# Override Amazon's "Quick Linker" default link styling with CSS

Tags: css

Edit:

**I solved this problem thanks to Emily and Mike below.** They told me how to find out where the CSS was coming from using Firebug.

---

For my site, I had a link black-colored with no underline, then with an underline when hovered. I turned this link into an Amazon "Quick Linker" link, and then it turned blue with an underline.

Someone on Stack Overflow told me to add `!important` to the CSS, but that didn't change the link format.

Any idea how I could turn this link to black-colored with no underline and still keep it an Amazon "Quick Linker" link?

Here is the code for the link:

```php
'<a type="amzn" category="books" class="links2">'.$row['site'].'</a>'
```

Here is the CSS for the link:

```
a.links2:link {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    margin-top: 6px !important;
    margin-bottom: 2px !important;
    margin-left: 2px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    height: 12px !important;
    vertical-align:middle !important;
}

a.links2:visited {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    margin-top: 6px !important;
    margin-bottom: 2px !important;
    margin-left: 2px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    height: 12px !important;
    vertical-align:middle !important;
}

a.links2:hover {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-decoration: underline !important; 
    text-align: left !important;
    margin-top: 6px !important;
    margin-bottom: 2px !important;
    margin-left: 2px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    height: 12px !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}

a.links2:active {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    margin-top: 6px !important;
    margin-bottom: 2px !important;
    margin-left: 2px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    height: 12px !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the link in Firebug? That would tell you where it is picking up the styles. Or do you have a live link you can post?

Comment: OK, I Googled Firebug.  I'll try downloading it and using it.  Thanks.

Comment: OK, now I have Firebug.  I see something that says "class="amazon_widget_US_8005_0"", but I'm not sure if this is making my links blue & underlined.

Comment: In the right hand side of Firebug, in the Style tab, what are the styles associated with amazon_widget_US_8005_0? Are they overriding your styles?

Comment: Mike, thanks.  I solved the problem thanks to your pointer.  I found out where the CSS was coming from, changed it, and now it looks the way I want.  And Emily, thanks for recommending Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that CSS is declared before the Amazon "Quick Linker"'s styles?  The quick linker script could also be setting the !important declaration, which would take precedence over your own declaration.  You would need to make sure your styles are set *after* the styles set by Amazon's script.